# Language switcher doesn't let me change language manually

Tags: multilingual

What do I have to configure in joomla so I am able to switch languages manually without having to change my browser language?

I built a joomla multi language site where I can switch the language with the language flag buttons.

Joomla recognizes and changes the content to the specified language by detecting my browser language. But when I wan't to change the language manually by clicking on one of the language flags, Joomla will refuse to change the language by staying on the same language.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to you Plugin Manager, ensure the Language Filter plugin is enabled. Open it and on the left and side you will see the option **Language Selection for new Visitors**. Try setting this to **Site Language**.

Also ensure that **Automatic Language Change** is set to **Yes**

Comment: I have the language filter enabled and automatic language change set to yes. When changing language selection for new visitors to site language it get's even worse, then my website will stay in the english section only even when using a different browser language :(

Comment: It should work. When Language Selection for new Visitors is set to Site Language, browser language is ignored. Please recheck your settings one more time. [Here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-configuration-multilanguage-site.html) is the nice tutorial for setting multilanguage site.

Comment: also check the session settings, as it might have stored your previous preferences